# How to select a record type when I click "New"?

Tags: page-layout, record-type

I'm still learning, so my question might be simple but I can't seem to find the answer I need on Salesforce help or trailhead...

I have created two `record types` for a **Contract object**, two `page layouts` as well. I'm stuck at two points, which I imagine are related...

You see in the image below, when you click **New**, you have a choice to select the record type you want for the Account object. How can I do that for the contract object?

[image]

Second point, of course I'd like to be able to assign a page layout to a record type, so that the right page layout gets displayed once I'm able to select a record type when I click New...

All I found so far was how to assign a record type to a user profile :/

Thank you for help!

Comment: Make sure you update your user's profile to grant them access to the required record types (plus map the record types to the required page layouts) and the UI will handle the rest.

Comment: Thank you, I had no clue about that detail! It fixed it. Thanks again for your time.